# Dynamically equivalent of numerical solution of $y' = f(y)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Consider an autonomous system $y' = f(y)$ and a fixed step size $h$. 
>  a) Show that the trapezoidal method applied $N$ times is equivalent to applying first half a step of forward Euler, (i.e forward Euler with step size $h/2$) followed by $N -1$  midpoint steps finishing off with half a step of backward Euler. 
>   b) Conclude that these two symmetric methods are dynamically equivalent ,i.e
>   for $h$ small enough their performance is very similar independently of $N$ even over a very long time $t_N =  N.h.$ 
>   c) However if $h$ is not small enough compared to the problems small parameter
>   say $\lambda^{-1}$ then these methods do not necessarily perform similarly. Construct an example where one of these methods blows up say (error $>10^5$)  while the other yields an error below $10^{-5}$.

My attempt: I finish part a) but I don't understand why two symmetric method are dynamically equivalent for small $h$. I think they are the same method and hence equivalent for every $h$. What am I wrong here? I have no clue in part c). Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance !

Comment: For part c, you'll want an example that is _stiff_ (i.e has slow and fast modes), which usually requires the use of implicit (i.e backward Euler) schemes to solve accurately. For example, $$y'(t) = -15y(t) + 4, \quad y(0) = 3, \quad y \in [0, 1]$$ with step sizes of $h = 1/7$. You should find the forward Euler blows up, but the backward Euler remains stable.

Comment: They are not the same method. The first and the last steps are different. But as $h\rightarrow 0$, those two steps will become less and less significant. Therefore the methods are asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: @Mattos thank you so much. Can I choose ex like $y' = -15y$ ?